# How to write a test case in golang on inserting, fetching, deleting and updating the data

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have to write the test cases for the inserting, fetching, deletion and updating the data. While searching on the internet I found a code and it works but I don't know how it works exactly. The code I have is given below can anybody please tell me in easy way that how I will understand the code.

```
package models

import(
    "testing"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "fmt"
)

func TestAddBlog(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct{
        query interface{}
    }
    tests := []struct{
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{
        {
            "first",
            args{
               bson.M{
                   "_id" : 4,
                   "title" : "Life",
                   "type" : "Motivation",
                   "description" : "If you skip anything then you will fail in the race of the life....",
                   "profile_image" : "/image1",
                   "date_time" : 1536062976,
                   "author" : "Charliee",
                   "status" : 1,
                   "slug" : "abc",
                   "comment_count" : 100,
                   "comment_status" : "q",
                },
            },
            true,
        },
        {
           "second",
           args{
               bson.M{
                   "_id" : 5,
                   "title" : "Life",
                   "type" : "Motivation",
                   "description" : "If you skip anything then you will fail in the race of the life....",
                   "profile_image" : "/image1",
                   "date_time" : 1536062976,
                   "author" : "Charliee",
                   "status" : 1,
                   "slug" : "abc",
                   "comment_count" : 100,
                   "comment_status" : "q",
                },
            },
            false,
        },
    }
    for _, k := range tests {
        t.Run(k.name, func (t *testing.T) {
            err := AddBlog(k.args.query)
            fmt.Println(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any specific issue you are facing with testing?

Comment: @vedhavyas no there is no issue but I don't know what is exactly written in this code

Comment: The code is just testing against `AddBlog`, which seems to take an object and creates it on Mongo DB.

Comment: @vedhavyas can you tell me that how I will write test case for the fetching the data

Comment: This is something I wrote sometime back. Maybe it can get you started - https://github.com/vedhavyas/p2p-users/blob/master/db/user_test.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I Have Provided With The Form Of Test Case Known as Table Driven Tests

```
type args struct {
}
tests := []struct {
    name string
    args args
    want bool
}{
    {
        "First",
        args{

        },
        true,
    },
    {
        "Second",
        args{

        },
        false,
    },
}
for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
    })
}
```

In The Following Code What we Do is:

*Declare A Slice of Struct([]struct) With Three Parameters

1.Name:- It Would Be used For naming the Test in t.Run.

2.Args:- Here We Specify the arguments That Are needed By The Function We are Going To Test.

3.Want:- This is the bool expression which will be used For Comparison with The output of our Result.

Now as in Your Code You have Added Something in the Database so You Need To call a Function Which Will Fetch the record.

If the err is equal to nil by the addblog Function.

After That You can Compare if all of the values are saved by comparing and saving the result as a bool which we can use for comparison with our want bool expression.

Something Like this Will happen:

```
 err:=  AddBlog(k.args.query)
 if err==nil{
 got,err:=fetchBlog(k.args.query)
 if val:=err==nil && got.id==id;val!=k.want{
   t.Fail()
  }
 }
```

Note:
Here I have Compared The Id Attribute as it Will be Unique .

You Need To Declare that in Your args First.

Comment: i understand what you are saying but while I'm fetching the record it will return all the record then in the condition of the comparing then it will compare all the ids with the given id?

Comment: you can use a function which fetches only a single record or as query is being passed in the parameters of the fetchblog function you can directly use bson.M{"_id":k.args.id} as a parameter. this way only a specific id will be fetched